# Codeigniter show stats of a user

Tags: database, codeigniter, join, statistics

I'm working on a community and I want to show a lot of user stats in the user profile.

What is the best practice to do?.

I have this now, but I don't think its the best way of doing it, so I will be really glad of you can explain me what I can do to load a lot of stats in my query:

```
//Get the stats of a user in hes profile
    function getState($username) {

        //it has false so it dont try to escape the COUNT()
        $this->db->select('username, firstname, lastname, freetext, imgPath, city, hood, online, level, 
        COUNT(forumThread.id) as totalThreads,
        COUNT(forumComments.id) as totalComments
        ', FALSE);
        $this->db->join('forumThread', 'forumThread.creater = users.username');
        $this->db->join('forumComments');
        $this->db->group_by('users.id');
        $this->db->where('username', $username);

        $statQuery = $this->db->get('users');

        return $statQuery->row();
    }
```

Comment: You don't have to set the second parameter in select to false because Codeigniter will not escape functions. In fact, the source code first splits the string using commas as delimiters. Then it goes through this array and adds backticks to each item if they aren't already there as each item is presumed to be a field, but if a parenthesis is found anywhere it will just keep the item as it is.

Answer (score 1):

Any time you start joining tables, you run the risk of making your query fairly slow (as the tables grow).

One option would be to cache the results so you don't have to run the query every time the page is loaded. (I think CI does give you query caching abilities)

Another option would be to have another field in the users table, which has the number of forum threads and the number of forum comments they have made. When you insert a new entry into the database, you increment this counter as well. So when loading the data you need in the stats page, you're just querying the 1 table.

The 2nd option does give you obviously a slightly bigger overhead, of running another query when you enter the other data, and decrementing when you delete one. And/Or creating maintenance script which makes sure that the values in the users table are actually accurate (and runs periodically in the background).

Anyway, I feel like I'm just rambling now. I hope some if that made sense!